# How to speed up Excel Calculations

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am very much a novice when it comes to vba programming, and as such have not been able to find/figure out a solution to my problem.

I have a vba script that runs through a button in an access form (excerpt below) that does a calculation in excel, for approximately 30,000 records (Inventory List worksheet). Further to this, the "Data1" worksheet has 1,000,000 records and the "Data2" worksheet has approximately 100,000 records. The calculation checks for how many pieces of information a "tag" requires and how many pieces of information the "tag" currently has in our database, and calculates a decimal value for completeness.

This all results in 100%  CPU usage when computing. I was wondering if anyone would have some pointers on how to improve the calculation so as to improve its running speed?

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub BUILD_INVENTORY_LIST_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Note: DTable is a variable entered earlier in the coding
Dim strWorksheetPathTable As String
    strWorksheetPathTable = "O:\GData\POC\DataMgmt\Reports\" & DTable & "\" & DTable & ".xls"

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim InventoryListSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("" & strWorksheetPathTable & "")
Set oBook = GetObject("" & strWorksheetPathTable & "")
Set InventoryListSheet = oBook.Sheets("InventoryList")

Dim NumberofTags As String
NumberofTags = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

If Len(Sheets("Data1").Name) > 0 Then
    With xlWB
        With InventoryListSheet
        .Range("O2").Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(Data1!A:A,A2,Data1!G:G,""Y"",Data1!E:E,""<>"")/(COUNTIFS(Data1!A:A,A2,Data1!G:G,""Y"")))"
        .Range("O2:O" & NumberofTags & "").FillDown
        End With
    End With
End If

If Len(Sheets("Data2").Name) > 0 Then
    With xlWB
        With InventoryListSheet
        .Range("P2").Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(Data2!A:A,A2,Data2!G:G,""Y"",Data2!E:E,""<>"")/(COUNTIFS(Data2!A:A,A2,Data2!G:G,""Y"")))"
        .Range("P2:P" & NumberofTags & "").FillDown
        End With
    End With
End If

xlWB.Save
xlWB.Close
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know if there is any other pieces of information is required that could influence any suggestions you may have. Thanks again

Comment: If an Excel calculation is causing your computer to overheat, you have bigger issues that calculation time.

Comment: "Overheat" is a bit of an exaggeration on my part. More so getting hot. But I know where you're coming from. Still, any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Is the majority of the calculation happening during `.FillDown`?

Comment: Yes indeed. This repeats the calculation for all 30,000 tags.

Comment: So you're filling down that formula to 30k rows? Wow, no wonder it's intensive. How long is it taking anyways?
If you can't simplify the formula, then your only other option would be to offload the calculations to a third party, i.e. an external application.

Comment: I haven't had it running for more than 20 minutes, so I'm not sure how long it takes. But the calculation taking longer than that simply isn't feasible for what I'm doing.

Comment: Yeah, an external application may be the only option to do this, if so I'll probably scrap it the calculation, or only use it for far smaller scopes of tags

Comment: There's one more thing I can suggestion doing, is first suspend automatic calculations, perform the fill, then allow automatic calculations. This may speed things up.
Source: http://www.zerrtech.com/content/stop-vba-automatic-calculation-using-applicationcalculation-manual

Comment: I'll look into this and let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help mate

Comment: Looks like I'm simply limited by my computer unfortunately. Thanks for all the help mate :)

Comment: Try replacing it with an SQL statement

Comment: What is the code behind `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`? Presumably a class module because it doesn't compile for me. Why are you instancing a new Excel? Why not `Application.Calculation = xlManual`; `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at top of procedure? Have you tried copying the formula with those settings instead of using the `.FillDown` method? I suspect there is recalculation happening as each cell is filled.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald The code is being called form Access.  The `DoCmd` space is very common in Access VBA

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion Mark, this is what was suggested by Reticulated Spine earlier in the source he linked, and has not worked. I feel as if this is simply limited by what my computer can do, since it takes it at least 0.5s to do each of these calcs, and has to do it 2x30,000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

or similarly this:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm

where relevant.

Comment: Thanks or the suggestion CLL. As this coding merely opens the excel process and does not open it up on screen, these suggestions will not work for my situation.